# Configure frame IDs for mavros local_position/odom

Tags: mavros, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a system of 4 UAVs with 4 pixhawks and 4 on-board computers. A ground station is controlling the ROS master. I have a problem managing UAV poses.
Mavros  publishes local_position/odom with child frame ID 'base_link'.
Since I have 4 UAVs operating in the same ROS space, this is a problem.

I looked through the documents but did not see how to set a parameter for child frame ID. Is there such parameter that I have missed?
If there isn't then running a node which listens to the topics (topics are namespaced with /uav1, /uav2 etc) and republish to a new topic with new frame IDs (naive, I know) the best way to approach this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254543/configure-frame-ids-for-mavros-local_position/odom/) by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 849 on 2017-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you read http://wiki.ros.org/mavros#mavros.2BAC8-Plugins.local_position ?

You need modified config.yaml for each drone node.

---

Originally posted by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) with karma: 404 on 2017-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Doolly](https://answers.ros.org/users/31599/doolly/) on 2017-08-16**:
I'm not familiar with yaml files
can you explain how little further?
is changing parameter through launch file to frame_id whatever I want is ok?